# AngularJS routing parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

`friendID = 1234;`

```
$route.when(
    "/friends/:friendID/raw",
    {
        event: "friends.view"
    }
);
```

When I run the above the URL in Chrome Dev Tools shows that the url tried is `http://domain.com/friends/raw?0=1&1=2&2=3&3=4`

is there a way to actually get it to run as `http://domain.com/friends/1234/raw`

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what's going on here with only this snippet.  Can you post the values of your JSON object?  At first glance, it appears that your object it's passing multiple values.  You might try setting its value to 1234 and see if it passes correctly.